Determine Origin of getObject Requests in AWS
My organization uses AWS, and there's been an influx of getObject requests to S3 causing our costs to skyrocket. I'd like to track down the source of these requests to get them under control, but am relatively inexperienced with AWS and am not sure the best place to start. I was thinking CloudTrail logs might be somewhat useful,  but not sure if that will actually give me the info I need and I'd like to avoid adding additional costs and tools if not absolutely necessary. I wanted to make sure there's not an alternative option I'm missing before I set that up. Is there somewhere I can go to see getObject request count grouped by IP address or individual?

You can either enable CloudTrail event logging or server access logging
